# Trigger Autohotkey on new window

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey, window-manager

How do I set an action to trigger whenever a new window opens in autohotkey?
For instance, I could set any Windows Explorer window to be marked as "Always on Top" as soon as it comes up. Or I could set any new Skype windows to always open on the second monitor, or always be semi-transparent, etc...

I think autohotkey can achieve this, but I don't know how. I need it to perform some arbitrary action on a new window as soon as it comes up.

Comment: Simiar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176757/autohotkey-window-appear-event which has a nice accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoHotkey is an off-spin created specifically for hot keys...

You might want to try the original [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) instead, it has a lot of automation features, including window events!

More specific, you can [find a script here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/90804-winmove-function-with-new-opened-window/) that tracks windows and acts on new windows.

```
#include <Array.au3>

; Initialize tracking arrays
Global $avWinListPrevious[1][2] = [[0, ""]], $avWinListCurrent

; Monitor unique window handles
While 1
    $avWinListCurrent = WinList("[REGEXPTITLE:.+[ \- ]GIMP]", "GNU Image Manipulation Program")
    For $n = $avWinListCurrent[0][0] To 1 Step -1
   ; Check has title and visible
        If ($avWinListCurrent[$n][0] <> "") And BitAND(WinGetState($avWinListCurrent[$n][1]), 2) Then
       ; Check for already seen
            $fFound = False
            For $i = 1 To $avWinListPrevious[0][0]
                If $avWinListCurrent[$n][1] = $avWinListPrevious[$i][1] Then
                    $fFound = True
                    ExitLoop
                EndIf
            Next

       ; New window found
            If Not $fFound Then
                WinMove("[REGEXPTITLE:.+[ \- ]GIMP]", "GNU Image Manipulation Program", 169, 0, 893, 771 )
            EndIf
        Else
            _ArrayDelete($avWinListCurrent, $n)
        EndIf
    Next
    $avWinListCurrent[0][0] = UBound($avWinListCurrent) - 1
    $avWinListPrevious = $avWinListCurrent
    Sleep(500)
WEnd
```

Comment: Not true, you can do this with AHK: http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic63673.html

Comment: @KingRadical: Why are you double posting? I did not state that its not possible.

Comment: Polling every 500 ms? terrible way to do it, and too much code for such a simple thing anyways. A good solution can be found in this AHK thread http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/85114-detecting-new-child-window/

Comment: Didn't wrote this myself, but you're free to post your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this would work nicely:
http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic63673.html

and in case the link changes or goes down for any reason:

```
;========================================================================
; 
; Template:     WinTrigger (former OnOpen/OnClose)
; Description:  Act upon (de)activation/(un)existance of programs/windows
; Online Ref.:  http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=63673
;
; Last Update:  15/Mar/2010 17:30
;
; Created by:   MasterFocus
;               http://www.autohotkey.net/~MasterFocus/AHK/
;
; Thanks to:    Lexikos, for improving it significantly
;               http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic43826.html#267338
;
;========================================================================
;
; This template contains two examples by default. You may remove them.
;
; * HOW TO ADD A PROGRAM to be checked upon (de)activation/(un)existance:
;
; 1. Add a variable named ProgWinTitle# (Configuration Section)
; containing the desired title/ahk_class/ahk_id/ahk_group
;
; 2. Add a variable named WinTrigger# (Configuration Section)
; containing the desired trigger ("Exist" or "Active")
;
; 3. Add labels named LabelTriggerOn# and/or LabelTriggerOff#
; (Custom Labels Section) containing the desired actions
;
; 4. You may also change CheckPeriod value if desired
;
;========================================================================

#Persistent

; ------ ------ CONFIGURATION SECTION ------ ------

; Program Titles
ProgWinTitle1 = ahk_class Notepad
WinTrigger1 = Exist
ProgWinTitle2 = Calculator
WinTrigger2 = Active

; SetTimer Period
CheckPeriod = 200

; ------ END OF CONFIGURATION SECTION ------ ------

SetTimer, LabelCheckTrigger, %CheckPeriod%
Return

; ------ ------ ------

LabelCheckTrigger:
  While ( ProgWinTitle%A_Index% != "" && WinTrigger := WinTrigger%A_Index% )
    if ( !ProgRunning%A_Index% != !Win%WinTrigger%( ProgWinTitle := ProgWinTitle%A_Index% ) )
      GoSubSafe( "LabelTriggerO" ( (ProgRunning%A_Index% := !ProgRunning%A_Index%) ? "n" : "ff" ) A_Index )
Return

; ------ ------ ------

GoSubSafe(mySub)
{
  if IsLabel(mySub)
    GoSub %mySub%
}

; ------ ------ CUSTOM LABEL SECTION ------ ------

LabelTriggerOn1:
LabelTriggerOff1:
LabelTriggerOn2:
  MsgBox % "A_ThisLabel:`t" A_ThisLabel "`nProgWinTitle:`t" ProgWinTitle "`nWinTrigger:`t" WinTrigger
Return

; ------ END OF CUSTOM LABEL SECTION ------ ------
```

Please note I did not write this code.

Answer (score 1):

This does it with AutoHotkey

```
#Persistent
Gui +LastFound
hWnd := WinExist()

DllCall("RegisterShellHookWindow", UInt,hWnd)
MsgNum := DllCall("RegisterWindowMessage", Str,"SHELLHOOK")
OnMessage(MsgNum, "ShellMessage")
Return

ShellMessage(wParam,lParam) {
  Local k
  If (wParam = 1) { ;  HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED := 1
    NewID := lParam
    SetTimer, Action, -1
  } else {
    ;SetTimer, Action, -1 ; this is to make it execute even on old windows. Probably more CPU intensive.
  }
}

Action:
  ; here put the action that you want to run when a new window is detected
    
Return
```